# How do I copy terms to a list in descending order?

Tags: java

I am trying to pass the variables `coeff` and `expo` to an arraylist called `poly`. When `poly` is empty, the two variables are stored. My problem is when `poly` is not empty which in this case would be the else statement, the compiler freezes up and throws the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Is there something wrong with the else statement that I am not aware of.

```
public void insert(int coeff, int expo) {

    Term a = new Term(coeff, expo);// Creates a new Term object with passed #'s

    if (poly.isEmpty()) {
        poly.add(a);

    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < poly.size(); i++) {
            Term one = poly.get(i);

            if (one.getExp() < a.getExp()) {
                poly.add(i, a);
            }
        }
        poly.add(a);
    }
 }
```

Comment: OutOfMemory exception...cool.

Comment: I bet it has something to do with that loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because , each time you are adding new element to `ArrayList` `poly` the size of `ArrayList` is increased , this leading to indefinite loop . You should try something like this:

```
else {
  int size = poly.size();//store the size of ArrayList poly in a variable so that the for loop is definite.
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Term one = poly.get(i);
    if (one.getExp() < a.getExp()) {//check this condition..I guess it is always true for each iteration.
      poly.add(i, a);
      i++;//after adding an element at index i increment it by 1
      size = size + 1;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to be sure without seeing more of your code, but it looks iffy that you add new elements to `poly` while iterating over it. If you're not careful, you could easily end up in an infinite loop.

If `add(i, a)` adds `a` at the `i`-th index, then you are guaranteed an infinite loop since you'll keep examining the same element over and over again as it keeps shifting to the right as you keep inserting `a` right in front of it.

Comment: I want to create a polynomial in descending order e.g. 3x^3+2x^2+x^1 . so for the first location in the array list I am able to plug in any number because the list is empty,but for the rest of the polynomial I have to visit each term of the list and compare their exponents and place them accordingly. That is why I am using the for

Comment: So what can I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that

```
if (one.getExp() < a.getExp())
```

always evaluates to true... causing an infinite loop because you will never reach poly.size while adding one to poly every time.